# PAM limits.conf not working on www-data in ubuntu oneric ocelot

Tags: linux, pam, ulimit

tried uncommenting pam_limits.so from the pam.d directory but no luck. Basic PAM seems to be installed as libpam are present in /usr/lib

Here is the ucommented part of limits.conf

```
www-data        hard    CPU     1
@www-data       hard    CPU     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found it I think. I had to add

```
ulimit -t 5
```

to

```
/etc/init.d/apache2
```

Found the solution at this debian thread http://lists.debian.org/debian-isp/2001/12/msg00218.html

I've been trying to find the solution for days. Hope this helps someone else.